# What's wrong with my ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266

After trying to upgrade firmware of ESP8266, it failed. I am not finding any response from it. It's just blinking a red LED.

What will I do now?

---

I had tried to upgrade the firmwire in different ways...but couldn't.The result is that i am not finding any wifi signal response in the network connection ...What's now?

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade firmware on the ESP8266 is hardcoded. Attempting to reflash it with known good firmware should restore functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct firmware depending on the version of the board you have, the family seems quite big:
[esp8266 wiki](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266-module-family)

There's nothing stopping you from experimenting and flashing different versions until you find the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that GPIO0 is not shorted to ground. Otherwise, try to reflash the firmware and when finished, leave GPIO0 floating to get out of firmware upgrading mode.